# Finding the menu.lst that is being used by grub on a multiboot/multipartition system

Tags: grub, legacy

How do I find which partition holds the menu.lst being used at boot time?

Not looking for multiple locations , as where the file could be, but where it is definitely to be found. (e.t. partition)
Is the file located on partition 1,2, or partition 8 ? 
The file in /boot/grub/menu.lst was used to display a grub-gretting screen, but which partition it was read from ? without going in to each and every partition and dig, what about a system that holds 8 or even more partitions ? How to find out ?

So the output should list a single location for the file .

grub version 0.97 (grub legacy)

Answer (score 0):

Grub 0.97 had only one location for menu.lst: `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.

That doesn't mean that your ancient distro didn't customize it, so you may still have to actually go in and look around.